# Binding a signal in a custom widget class

Tags: python, gtk, signals, gtk3, pygobject

I'm trying to add a custom `Gtk.ListBoxRow` to a `Gtk.ListBox`. This custom row is defined in the `CustomRow` class in the following way:

```
class CustomRow(Gtk.ListBoxRow):
    def __init__(self, label):
        super().__init__()

        button = Gtk.Button(label='button')
        label = Gtk.Label(label=label)
        box = Gtk.Box()
        box.add(button)
        box.add(label)

        self.add(box)


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...

        self.listbox = Gtk.ListBox()
        ...
        self.listbox.add(CustomRow('label'))

    def button_clicked(self):
        print('button clicked')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

What I now want to do is have is have the `button` be bound to `button_clicked` function found in `Main` - this function will remove the row from the listbox. Issue is that I have no idea how to do this from another class.

Comment: Why not pass the button to the custom row constructor? You could bind the signal in `Main` and then pass the button to `CustomRow`.

Comment: True, that is a possibility, though it makes the code less modular. I'd say this is a good temporary solution, though not an ideal one

Comment: In terms of modularity, I would say putting widget (especially related ones) in Main is not ideal as well. An ideal solution would be to have a custom ListBox that would handle all this complexity. Main would not be aware of it.

Comment: That's a good idea, I might implement this instead.

Comment: Did you solve this?